# VueJS access nested component data value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

> Parent Component contains **one Address Component**:

```
// ParentComponent.vue
<Address ref="childAddress"></Address>
```

> Address Component contains **many contact components** :

```
// AddressComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <Contact ref="childContact"></Contact>
    <Contact ref="childContact"></Contact>
    <Contact ref="childContact"></Contact>
  </div>
</template>
export default {
  components: { Contact },
  data: () => ({
    address_inputs: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    getAddresses() {
      // RETURN address_inputs
    }
  }
}
```

> Contact Component container:

```
// ContactComponent.vue
    <template>
      <div>
        contact component
      </div>
    </template>
    export default {
      components: { Contact },
      data: () => ({
        contact_inputs: [],
      }),
      methods: {
        getContacts() {
          // RETURN contact_inputs
        }
      }
    }
```

> What I am trying to do:

I am trying to get `address_inputs[]` from **AddressComponent** and `contact_inputs[]` from **ContactComponent** in the **ParentComponent**.

> What I have  tried:

I have tried to call `getAddresses` in **AddressComponent** using:
`this.$refs.childAddress.getAddresses();`

And this works fine but I could not then access the **ContactComponent** `contact_input[]` value.

Comment: i think that [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org) is suitable for this case

Comment: I am using Vuex but to store my API values and state but in this case I just want object from child component to parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$refs attribute is feature that allow you to manipulate DOM for example change div color so you are going wrong way.

If you want pass data from parent to component you should use props. If you want recive data from child to parent you have to use events.

In your example you are trying to pass data from child to parent so in your child component write input change method which emit event for example:
`this.$emit('testEvent', dataFromInput);`

End then in your parent template you can catch it

```
<Contact ref="childContact" @testEvent="printData"></Contact>
```

and in parent js part

```
methods: {
  printData(dataFromInput) {
    console.log(dataFromInput);
  }
}
```

that's all.

Comment: I am using the Contact inputs and store them in an object so how I pass this object using events?

Comment: You can use watch and on value change trigger event with data.  watch: {
    contact_inputs: function (val) {
      this.$emit('testEvent', val);
    },